# xdotool type error. Can't type a field starting from - (hyphen/dash) with . (dot) in the same field

Tags: command-line, xdotool

```
$ xdotool type -14.7873
type: unrecognized option '-14.7873'
Usage: type [--window windowid] [--delay milliseconds] <things to type>
--window <windowid>    - specify a window to send keys to
--delay <milliseconds> - delay between keystrokes
--clearmodifiers       - reset active modifiers (alt, etc) while typing
--args N  - how many arguments to expect in the exec command. This is
            useful for ending an exec and continuing with more xdotool
            commands
--terminator TERM - similar to --args, specifies a terminator that
                    marks the end of 'exec' arguments. This is useful
                    for continuing with more xdotool commands.
-h, --help             - show this help output
```

Answer (score 7):

Although I can't find it documented in the manual page, `xdotool type` appears to accept a GNU style `--` sequence to indicate the end of option arguments i.e.

```
xdotool type -- -14.7873
```

Comment: @NeerajBisht Please click the checkmark beside the answer to mark it as "accepted". :)